# I get TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nativeModule.__expo_module_name__') when update Expo SDK

Tags: react-native, expo

I use the Expo 45 version, which is no longer available. For this reason, I am trying to upgrade, but when I run the application after upgrading, I get the following error.

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I read the following article but again I could not find a solution. https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/application-has-not-been-registered/

The output of `yarn why react-native-safe-area-context` is as follows.

```
yarn why v1.22.19
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "react-native-safe-area-context"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "react-native-safe-area-context@4.5.0"
info Has been hoisted to "react-native-safe-area-context"
info This module exists because it's specified in "dependencies".
info Disk size without dependencies: "1004KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1004KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "1004KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 0
✨  Done in 0.22s.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this error?

Edit:

I found the part that was causing the problem.
The `expo-ads-admob` package was causing this error. When I uninstalled the package, the problem disappeared. But I couldn't find exactly why this package was causing this error. I continue to research.

Edit 2:

https://blog.expo.dev/adding-admob-to-your-expo-project-aa4e48ac848

The update note to this article says that this package has been discontinued. I think the error was caused by a version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same error at the moment and it started when I installed expo-location.

Edit: I later realized it's because I imported location in the following form ==> `import * as Location from "expo-location"`